# Automating "enter" keypresses for bash script generating ssh keys

Tags: bash

I would like to create script, which simply runs `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. But how to pass to it 3 times enter?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f my.key
```

`-N ""` tells it to use an empty passphrase (the same as two of the enters in an interactive script)

`-f my.key` tells it to store the key into `my.key` (change as you see fit).

The whole thing runs without you needing to supply any enter keys :)

To send enters to an interactive script:

```
echo -e "\n\n\n" | ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Comment: It is correct anwser, but i still would like to know how to press enter more then one time - in another script.

Comment: Sure thing - updated the answer to include how to send newlines to a script.

Comment: echo -e "\n\n\n" | sshkeygen -t rsa is not working for me, can you try it yourself? It pass only first enter. But on other, simple script it works.

Comment: I tested it before I posted it - it works fine, although it looks like the dash from `ssh-keygen` got dropped - did you add that back in? {edited}  Also - you can't run the script more than once - it changes the questions to confirm you want to overwrite the existing `_rsa` keyfile (so a y or n needs to be supplied)

Comment: I'd recommend using `yes ""` instead of `echo -e "\n\n\n"` (`yes` outputs whatever argument is given [or "y" by default] in infinity – perfect for these situations where one just want to provide a "yes" answer to whatever a program might prompt for). `yes` is shorter, and should `ssh-keygen` ever add a question, that will automatically be answered in too. :)

Comment: @zrajm how would that be used? `yes "" | ssh-keygen...` ? because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: 'yes "y"|...` didn't work. Only sent it to the first prompt.

Comment: I've tested all the above. None work. This works:

`echo -e "\n"|ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ""`

Comment: `echo -e` isn't *guaranteed* to work at all -- even in bash, it will just echo `-e` as literal output when both `xpg_echo` and `posix` flags are enabled; non-bash shells may treat it that way out-of-the-box. `printf '\n'` is much more reliable. See the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the POSIX `echo` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: I made slight modification so I could use this for GitHub - `echo -e "\n\n\n" | ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemail@someaccount.com"`.  Worked great.  Thanks @Rudu

Comment: For Windows use `-N '""'` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767488/automate-ssh-keygen-t-rsa-so-it-does-not-ask-for-a-passphrase/14946700

Answer (score 23):

a version with passphrase is:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "comment" -P "examplePassphrase" -f "desired pathAndName" -q
```

- the -q is for silent

Source is http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen

Comment: Use -P for an existing passphrase, use -N for a new one

Comment: what is q for? what is the use of silent

Answer (score 4):

Agree with [Michel Marro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4718282/michel-marro) except that it needs some more:
If the file already exists, it will still be interactive asking if it has to overwrite it.

Use the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235179/how-execute-ssh-keygen-without-prompt).

```
yes y | ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' >/dev/null
```

The redirection to null is necessary to silence the overwrite message.

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended to use [ed25519](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to) for security and performance.

```
yes "y" | ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519 -C "Bla Bla" -f /mypath/bla -N ""
```

here

`-o` OpenSSH key format instead of older PEM (needs OpenSSH 6.5+)

`-a` Number of primality test while screening DH-GEX candidates

`-t` Type of key (ed25519, RSA, DSA etc.)

`-f /mypath/bla` The output file path and name

`-N ""` Use empty passphase

and `yes "y"` for no interaction.

It will generate two files

```
/mypath/bla
/mypath/bla.pub
```

where the `bla` file is private and `bla.pub` is public.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "\n"|ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ""
```

Comment: Eh? This actually has *fewer* newlines than one of the answers you claim don't work (and that's on the subset of platforms where `echo -e` emits something other than `-e` at all, which is not everywhere `ssh-keygen` is available).

Comment: ...to be clear, I make production use of `ssh-keygen -N ''` as part of an automated install procedure, and it doesn't read stdin at all, so there's no need for the `echo` (*any* `echo` variant) piped into it. (Granted, I believe stdin is connected to `/dev/null` in my production use case; there could well be different behavior when it's attached to a TTY, but the better answer is `</dev/null` rather than `echo ... |`)

Comment: It prompts me for a filename:

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -N ''
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/dlyons/.ssh/id_rsa):`