# How to install beehive on windows, to allow remote execution of hql scripts

Tags: java, hive, git-bash, azure-hdinsight, beeline

**How do you run beeline on local machine once you've downloaded the jar files?**

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919525) (for Ubuntu), you don't need to do a complete install of Hive to run the `beeline` CLI. You just need to download the relevant jars.

To determine the files to download for the `beeline` CLI, I've followed the instructions here, and created a script to run in **Git Bash**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-hive-jdbc-driver#connect-with-squirrel-sql-client

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# References:
# -----------
#
#   Insert multi-line string into a file
#       https://stackoverflow.com/a/23929367/893766
#
#   Setup ssh programatically
#       https://stackoverflow.com/a/3659691/893766
#       https://superuser.com/a/411991/174619
#       https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/new-ssh-key-for-a-new-different-user?answer=38759
#       https://superuser.com/a/1052675/174619
#
#   Relevant files to copy from cluster for hive drivers
#       https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-hive-jdbc-driver#connect-with-squirrel-sql-client
#
#   Loop through array of strings
#       https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880633/893766
#
#
# Helpful commands
# ----------------
#
#   Copy and paste into terminal and run to generate removal command
#       echo "ssh hive ${SSH_HOSTNAME} \"sed -i.bak '/${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME}/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys\""


# control variables
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "SETTING CONTROL VARIABLES"
echo
echo "..."
HDINSIGHT_CLUSTER_NAME="<CLUSTERNAME>.azurehdinsight.net"
HDINSIGHT_USER_NAME="sshuser"
SSH_HOST_NAME="hive"
SSH_KEY_PATH=~/.ssh/"${SSH_HOST_NAME}"
LOCAL_HIVE_DIR="/c/ProgramData/hive"
SSH_CONFIG_PATH=~/.ssh/config
SSH_CONFIG="Host ${SSH_HOST_NAME}
   Hostname ${HDINSIGHT_CLUSTER_NAME}
   User ${HDINSIGHT_USER_NAME}
   IdentityFile ${SSH_KEY_PATH}
"
declare -a FILE_GLOBS=(
    "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/hadoop-common.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/hadoop-auth.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/log4j-*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/slf4j-*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-*-1.2*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/httpclient-*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/httpcore-*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/libthrift-*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/libfb*.jar"
    "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/commons-logging-*.jar"
)
echo


# create ssh key for hive access
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "CREATING SSH KEY"
echo 
yes "y" | ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ${SSH_KEY_PATH}
echo 


# add hive ssh config for easier use in the terminal
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "SETTING SSH CONFIG FOR NEW KEY"
echo
echo -e "${SSH_CONFIG}" | tee ${SSH_CONFIG_PATH}
echo


# copy ssh key to edge node
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "COPYING SSH KEY TO EDGE NODE FOR SECURE PASSWORD-LESS ACCESS"
echo 
ssh-copy-id -i ${SSH_KEY_PATH} $HDINSIGHT_USER_NAME@$HDINSIGHT_CLUSTER_NAME
echo

# create local directory for hive drivers
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "CREATING DIRECTORY FOR HIVE DRIVERS"
echo 
mkdir -p -v ${LOCAL_HIVE_DIR}
echo

# download hive drivers from edge node to local directory
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "DOWNLOADING HIVE DRIVERS TO:"
echo "\t${LOCAL_HIVE_DIR}"
echo 
for glob in "${FILE_GLOBS[@]}"
do
   echo "Processing glob: ${glob}"
   echo -e "\tscp -p ${SSH_HOST_NAME}:${glob} ${LOCAL_HIVE_DIR}"
   scp -p ${SSH_HOST_NAME}:"${glob}" ${LOCAL_HIVE_DIR}
   echo
done
echo


# inform user of ssh usage
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "OUTPUT"
echo -e "
    Command to connect to edge node:
        ssh ${SSH_HOST_NAME}

    Hive drivers installed at:
        ${LOCAL_HIVE_DIR}

    To configure JDBC clients visit:
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-hive-jdbc-driver

    Use the 'beeline' commandline client for submitting and debugging scripts:
        https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-Beeline%E2%80%93CommandLineShell!quit

    ssh key location:
        ${SSH_KEY_PATH}

    ssh config location:
        ${SSH_CONFIG_PATH}

    view authorised ssh keys on the edge node with the following command:
        ssh ${SSH_HOST_NAME} \"cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys\"

    you can remove your ssh key from the edge node with the following command:
        ssh ${SSH_HOST_NAME} \"sed -i.bak '/${USERNAME}@${HOSTNAME}/d' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys\"
"
echo 
echo "Driver installation script has finished running"
```

This downloaded the following files:

```bsh
$ ls -la /c/ProgramData/hive
total 56204
drwxr-xr-x 1 adria 197609        0 Feb 26 15:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 adria 197609        0 Feb 26 16:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    62050 Apr  3  2017 commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    79075 Apr  4  2017 hadoop-auth.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609  3604047 Apr  4  2017 hadoop-common.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   122837 Apr  4  2017 hive-accumulo-handler-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    49706 Apr  4  2017 hive-ant-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   144508 Apr  4  2017 hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    40077 Apr  4  2017 hive-cli-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   342718 Apr  4  2017 hive-common-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   122723 Apr  4  2017 hive-contrib-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609 21703871 Apr  4  2017 hive-exec-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   118706 Apr  4  2017 hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    29113 Apr  4  2017 hive-hwi-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   106388 Apr  4  2017 hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609 19636098 Apr  4  2017 hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7-standalone.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609  6057211 Apr  4  2017 hive-metastore-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   924634 Apr  4  2017 hive-serde-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609  1983806 Apr  4  2017 hive-service-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    32386 Apr  4  2017 hive-shims-0.20S-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    62039 Apr  4  2017 hive-shims-0.23-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    10419 Apr  4  2017 hive-shims-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   112764 Apr  4  2017 hive-shims-common-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    13562 Apr  4  2017 hive-shims-scheduler-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   719304 Apr  3  2017 httpclient-4.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   321639 Apr  3  2017 httpcore-4.4.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   313702 Apr  3  2017 libfb303-0.9.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   234201 Apr  3  2017 libthrift-0.9.3.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609   489884 Apr  4  2017 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609    32119 Apr  4  2017 slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adria 197609     8866 Apr  4  2017 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
```

Java info:

```bsh
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode, sharing)

$ which java
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java
```

Now comes the part I have no idea about...

How do you run `beeline` on local machine once you've downloaded the jar files?

**What I've tried**

```bsh
$ cd /c/ProgramData/hive

$ java hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar

$ java -jar hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
no main manifest attribute, in hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar

$ java -cp /c/ProgramData/hive -jar hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
no main manifest attribute, in hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
```

---

## UPDATE #1

I've uninstalled the JRE 8 and installed JDK 9

```bsh
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin

$ java -version
java version "9.0.4"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)

$ which java
/c/Program Files/Java/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java

$ javac -version
javac 9.0.4
```

Contents of the beeline jar are as follows:

```bsh
$ jar tvf hive-beeline-1.2.1000.2.5.4.2-7.jar
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:28 AEST 2017 META-INF/
   436 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/util/
  9839 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 BeeLine.properties
  1139 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 beeline-log4j.properties
   164 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 META-INF/NOTICE
 11358 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 META-INF/LICENSE
 27286 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
  2308 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 sql-keywords.properties
  4658 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/Reflector.class
  2767 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/AbstractCommandHandler.class
  1196 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineCompleter.class
 38069 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/Commands.class
  5901 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/ColorBuffer.class
  1790 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/XMLElementOutputFormat.class
  1007 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DatabaseConnection$Schema$Table.class
  2309 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineCommandCompleter.class
  1973 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/ReflectiveCommandHandler.class
   264 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineOpts$Env.class
  2026 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/Commands$1.class
   894 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DriverInfo.class
  4785 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper.class
   181 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/OutputFormat.class
  2382 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$OracleCommandParser.class
  1522 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$NestedScriptParser$CommandType.class
   669 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/Commands$2.class
  4188 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/SeparatedValuesOutputFormat.class
  2671 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DatabaseConnection$Schema.class
   902 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$NestedScriptParser.class
  2532 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/Rows$Row.class
  1128 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/AbstractOutputFormat.class
  1219 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLine$1.class
   194 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineSignalHandler.class
 17720 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaTool.class
 16547 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineOpts.class
   395 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineOpts$Ignore.class
  2490 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/IncrementalRows.class
  3181 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/Rows.class
  2599 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$DerbyCommandParser.class
  4112 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/TableOutputFormat.class
  2289 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DeprecatedSeparatedValuesOutputFormat.class
  1209 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/OutputFile.class
  1075 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/TableNameCompletor.class
  2207 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/util/QFileClient$RegexFilterSet.class
   242 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/util/QFileClient$1.class
  9552 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/util/QFileClient.class
  1059 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/SunSignalHandler.class
  1912 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/XMLAttributeOutputFormat.class
   431 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BooleanCompleter.class
  1289 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DatabaseConnection$1.class
  2928 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$PostgresCommandParser.class
  1792 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLine$BeelineParser.class
  4068 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$AbstractCommandParser.class
   598 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/ColorBuffer$ColorAttr.class
  2220 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/VerticalOutputFormat.class
  4011 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/SQLCompleter.class
  2279 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BufferedRows.class
  9246 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DatabaseConnection.class
  1807 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DatabaseConnections.class
  2370 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$MSSQLCommandParser.class
   873 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/DatabaseConnection$Schema$Table$Column.class
   663 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLineOpts$1.class
  2195 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$AzureDBCommandParser.class
  2792 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/HiveSchemaHelper$MySqlCommandParser.class
  6656 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/ClassNameCompleter.class
 47773 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/BeeLine.class
   467 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 org/apache/hive/beeline/CommandHandler.class
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:28 AEST 2017 META-INF/maven/
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:28 AEST 2017 META-INF/maven/org.apache.hive/
     0 Tue Apr 04 12:16:28 AEST 2017 META-INF/maven/org.apache.hive/hive-beeline/
  5422 Tue Apr 04 12:08:16 AEST 2017 META-INF/maven/org.apache.hive/hive-beeline/pom.xml
   125 Tue Apr 04 12:16:26 AEST 2017 META-INF/maven/org.apache.hive/hive-beeline/pom.properties
```

Comment: was this ever resolved?

Comment: Not yet, have been puled onto other work, but maybe revisiting this within the next few months, so hopefully will get sometime to resolve.